# A way to parameterize volume inside cone in cylindrical coordinates?

Tags: cylindrical-coordinates

Is there a way to paramterize the volume inside a cone in cylindrical coordinates? z = r only gives the surface, not the volume inside. 
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about $0 \le z \le T$, $0 \le r \le z$, $0 \le \theta \le 2\pi$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I thought of the same answer but I suspect where I went wrong was I did 0 <= z <= r.

Comment: Actually, would 0<=z<=r work as well?

Comment: Never mind, it creates half of a cone on its side.